# React Profiler - proper names of memo'd components

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the React DevTools chrome extension to profile my component's rerenders.

However, components that have an anonymous function inside of `memo` show up just as `anynymous` inside the render graph.

Therefore, I've got to write this:

```
export const Number = memo(function Number(props) {
   return <div>something</div>
});
```

...instead of this:

```
export const Number = memo(props => {
   return <div>something</div>
});
```

Is there any way to specify component name just once?

Comment: did you tried `export default React.memo(Number)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you will need to mention the component name twice for React 16.x, i.e you need to follow this pattern

```
const Number = (props => {
   return <div>something</div>
});

export default memo(Number)
```